# vagrant and ubunutu: pip install jupyter error: Storing debug log for failure in /home/vagrant/.pip/pip.log

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, jupyter-notebook

I want to install jupyter on ubuntu 14.04(vagrant) with the command: sudo pip install jupyter, but there is error, could you tell me how to solve it.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ pip install jupyter
Downloading/unpacking jupyter
  Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Downloading ipywidgets-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46kB): 46kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in                                                                                                              run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundl                                                                                                             e=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_file                                                                                                             s
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resourc                                                                                                             es.py", line 2291, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resourc                                                                                                             es.py", line 2484, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resourc                                                                                                             es.py", line 2508, in _compute_dependencies
    parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resourc                                                                                                             es.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    next = lambda o: o.next()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resourc                                                                                                             es.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resourc                                                                                                             es.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'widgetsnbextension ~=2.0.0', 'at', ' ~                                                                                                             =2.0.0')

Storing debug log for failure in /home/vagrant/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. Since the pip version is 1.5.4 (you can confirm it by pip -V), upgrade pip is necessary. At the beginning, I can't upgrade pip with:   pip install --upgrade pip. I used another way to upgrade pip (https://askubuntu.com/questions/775942/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-pip-when-i-already-installed-the-provided-b):

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/e7/a8/7556133689add8d1a54c0b14aeff0acb03c64707ce100ecd53934da1aa13/pip-8.1.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf pip-8.1.2.tar.gz
cd pip-8.1.2
sudo python setup.py install
```

then upgrade to latest version of pip by: pip install --upgrade pip

then I can install jupyter by: sudo pip install jupyter.