# how to install install some Python packages, debug log output?

Tags: python

I am trying to execute this instruction:

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I foun this error:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pyzmq/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install 
--record /tmp/pip-JB30wJ-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 
in /tmp/pip_build_root/pyzmq

Storing debug log for failure in /home/userrr/.pip/pip.log
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the debug log output into the question.

Comment: Please also edit the `requirements.txt` file into the question

Comment: No, I mean you should take the file that is pointed to in the command output `/home/userrr/.pip/pip.log` and edit it into the question. Please also take the `requirements.txt` file and edit it's content into the question.

Comment: Dear @MegaIng In facts, this is really what I need in my instruction while Trying to install openwsn https://openwsn.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OW/pages/29196302/Kickstart+Linux

Comment: try this `sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python` then `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014318/vagrant-and-ubunutu-pip-install-jupyter-error-storing-debug-log-for-failure-in

Comment: @EsirKings I found this error 'Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.'

Comment: did you use `sudo` ??

Comment: @EsirKings yes I did

Comment: if you don't mind you can join this quick hangouts call and I can try and help you out. https://hangouts.google.com/call/ubpEu007M8OOEjQIBR2rAAEI